# Fill Array from another column SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I need help whit my Code (PostgreSQL).

I get in my row Result `{{2.0,10}{2.0,10}}` but I want `{{2.0,10}{3.0,20}}`.
I don't know where my error is. Result is text `[ ]` its must be a 2D Array

This is Table1

| Nummer | Name | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Kevin |  |

This is Table2

| Nummer | Exam | ProfNr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2.0 | 10 |
| 01 | 3.0 | 20 |

My Code is

```
update public."Table1" as t1
   set "Result" = ARRAY[[t2."Exam", t2."ProfNr"],[t2."Exam",t2."ProfNr"]]
from public."Table2" as t2 
where t1."Nummer"= 01
and t2."Nummer"=01;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate rows to make this happen.  This CTE should help clarify what I mean:

```
with buildarr as (
  select nummer, array_agg(array[exam, profnr]) result
    from table2
   group by nummer
)
update table1
   set result = buildarr.result
  from buildarr
 where buildarr.nummer = table1.nummer;
```

[Working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e4efb91d66283a699903eb28ac49043e)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pre-aggregate:

```
update public."Table1" as t1
   set "Result" = t2.ar
from (select array_agg(array[t2."Exam", t2."ProfNr"])) as ar
      from public."Table2" as t2 
      where t2."Nummer" = 01
     ) t2
where t1."Nummer"= 01;
```